# GridViewItem with height greater than its GridView height

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have GridView with fixed width and height of items. But I want some items to exceed that fixed height to contain more data. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg02J.png)
I don't want to increase height of GridView - this will cause decreasing of the touch area of other controls that lie under GridView.

Is there any solution?
Thank you!

Concept [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg02J.png)

Comment: If I understand your question, you want `GridView` children to be bigger than the parent `GridView`? Post a wireframe picture or concept so people can get clear picture.

Comment: Yes, I want child higher than GridView. I tryed to draw some type of concept but it looks ugly :(

Comment: ugly is fine if it delivers the message.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](http://lh5.ggpht.com/-HBo-oiVwm-Q/UDWuSVP6DTI/AAAAAAAANA4/5HgVJbi0Roo/image_thumb%25255B1%25255D.png?imgmax=800)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want variable sized tiles in your grid view just like in the start screen? If so then this article should help
http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/03/07/Databinding-to-the-VariableSizedWrapGrid-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx

Comment: No, I want gridviewitems to be drawn outside of gridview bounds.

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov your design choices are not logical. You shouldn't be drawing `Gridview` items outside the bounds of the parent as it doesn't really makes any sense. You should rethink your design strategy and come up with a better solution than what you have right now.

Comment: Quite frankly wouldn't your design look ugly if the item extended the gridview bounds? Rather a bigger item compared to the rest but still part of grid view would look good? anyway dont think it can be done as part of the grid view....maybe u can break the grid view there and add an item separately to the grid and then create another gridview and continue with it?

Comment: It looks nice on real mockups (realy I need only one, selected, item to be expanded). I'm not sure it's possible to achive this goal with two gridviews because of problems with scrolling and synchronization.

Comment: ohh so u want the size of the item to be increased on selection?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any solution?