# GridView with GridViewItem Cutoff

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a WP8.1 Page created with this XAML:
`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView x:Name="gridCategory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SizeChanged="gridCategory_SizeChanged">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

`

The DataSource of `<Image>` is simply a list of objects with property `ImagePath` is the path to images in a folder.
Data is populated into the `GridView` inside method `OnNavigatedTo`.

My problem is that it shows this when running inside the emulator.

[image]

But this is what I want:

[image]

I can't increase the height of `RowDefinition` or set fixed size for `<Image>`.

Is there any way to make the images inside the GridView scale smaller so that their height will fit the height of GridViewItem and will not be cutoff ?

I looked at this post: [GridViewItem with height greater than its GridView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127406/gridviewitem-with-height-greater-than-its-gridview-height), but that doesn't help.

Comment: Please, share runtime environment like hardware, software tool version, and etc. Also if you find a solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way in 8.1.  I think you'll have to do math to compute the Height you want for the Image Elements and assign that Height via binding like you do for the ImageSource.  You'll likely have to set the Height to the value you get in gridCategory_SizeChanged minus a bit.  You might also have to change the ItemContainerStyle to remove extra space.